# Magento 1.4 paypal bug

Tags: magento, paypal

i try to get the paypal payment run in my magento 1.4 but there is a serious problem with the workflow. after i select paypal and get routed to the paypal account to send the money you normally come back automatically into the magento shop to finish the order, but in my case magento tells you there is aproblem with the adress field. paypal does'nt send the adress back to magento correctly:

```
Error: Please check shipping address information. Please enter last name.
```

is this a known bug or is there a patch or workaround?

please help!
thnx.

Comment: anything new here?
hey, everybody, do you just don't use paypal or am I the only one who downloaded a buggy version?
maybe I have to change the shop system to some working one...

Comment: Have you tried a fresh install? Is there anything abnormal about your addresses? Also, can you use logging to see what address is returned?

Comment: unfortunately I don't have the possibilities to check these things out. but I found some other people with the same issue here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/195086/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error seems to be in **/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Api/Nvp.php**. Looks like the vars aren't mapped well. Because I couldn't find the concrete error in this file, I did a bit dirty workaround in **/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php**.

In **1.4.2** just replace the method **returnFromPaypal()** with the following code...

```
public function returnFromPaypal($token)
{
    $this->_getApi();
    $this->_api->setToken($token)
        ->callGetExpressCheckoutDetails();

    // import billing address
    $billingAddress = $this->_quote->getBillingAddress();
    $exportedBillingAddress = $this->_api->getExportedBillingAddress();

    // import shipping address
    $exportedShippingAddress = $this->_api->getExportedShippingAddress();
    if (!$this->_quote->getIsVirtual()) {
        $shippingAddress = $this->_quote->getShippingAddress();
        if ($shippingAddress) {
            if ($exportedShippingAddress) {
                foreach ($exportedShippingAddress->getExportedKeys() as $key) {
                    if('firstname' == $key || 'lastname' == $key){
                        continue;
                    } // if
                    $shippingAddress->setDataUsingMethod($key, $exportedShippingAddress->getData($key));
                    $billingAddress->setDataUsingMethod($key, $exportedShippingAddress->getData($key));
                }

                // Correct First- and Lastnames
                list($_firstname, $_lastname) = explode(' ', $exportedShippingAddress->getData('firstname'));

                $shippingAddress->setDataUsingMethod('firstname', $_firstname);
                $billingAddress->setDataUsingMethod('firstname', $_firstname);

                $shippingAddress->setDataUsingMethod('lastname', $_lastname);
                $billingAddress->setDataUsingMethod('lastname', $_lastname);

                $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true);
            }

            // import shipping method
            $code = '';
            if ($this->_api->getShippingRateCode()) {
                if ($code = $this->_matchShippingMethodCode($shippingAddress, $this->_api->getShippingRateCode())) {
                     // possible bug of double collecting rates :-/
                    $shippingAddress->setShippingMethod($code)->setCollectShippingRates(true);
                }
            }
            $this->_quote->getPayment()->setAdditionalInformation(self::PAYMENT_INFO_TRANSPORT_SHIPPING_METHOD, $code);
        }
    }
    $this->_ignoreAddressValidation();

    // import payment info
    $payment = $this->_quote->getPayment();
    $payment->setMethod($this->_methodType);
    Mage::getSingleton('paypal/info')->importToPayment($this->_api, $payment);
    $payment->setAdditionalInformation(self::PAYMENT_INFO_TRANSPORT_PAYER_ID, $this->_api->getPayerId())
        ->setAdditionalInformation(self::PAYMENT_INFO_TRANSPORT_TOKEN, $token)
    ;
    $this->_quote->collectTotals()->save();
}
```

The modified code replaces the whole billing address with the shipping address and pushes the name given in $firstname into $firstname and $lastname.

not clean, but working. :-)

Comment: Works for me too, on Magento 1.6.2

Answer (score 0):

any luck finding a solution to this, I'm having the same issue.

--- update ---

I finally figured out what was happening on this one for me.  I had the Custom Shipping Admin module installed and it was overriding the address controller that validates the order.  I updated the overrided module to reflect the version of Magento I was on and it worked.. no problems.  Hope this helps someone.